# Different C# apps accessing database through Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, transactions, linq-to-entities, console-application

I have a C# console application which does some processing and then writes to the database. I have it deployed multiple times on a server with different config settings to do slightly different things. However, they all have to write to the same database (and may need to insert the same data into to the same table if it doesn't already exist) using Linq to Entities.

If I were using threads I could lock the method, or stored procedures I could queue up the writes to avoid clashes, but is there any way to keep these as seperate applications, and prevent them both trying to write the same thing to the database at the same time?

I'm getting an exception every so often when there is a conflict.

**Edit:**

I'm not necessarily trying to debug why I'm getting the exception, looking more for any suggestions of a 'best practice' way of doing this e.g. Should this be handled at the console app level, the L2E level, or the database level.

Comment: Getting an ...? Exception? What does it say?

Comment: At the moment its hidden inside some friendly error text : ) I'll try to find out the exact error message

Comment: @Ilya Smagin - Its Linq to Entities not Linq to SQL...

Comment: @Ilya: That's a hopeless comment. OP states l2e *not* linq2sql. Besides, a blanket comment without justification is worse than pointless. Back yourself up or don't bother posting. We're running a website with over 1m uniques/month using linq2sql, so I'd be interested in why you think it's so bogus.

Comment: @spender, http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/ Here's a performance comparison between different ORMs. Drapper-net is the one written and used by StackOverflow. Guess why they gave up Linq? Yes, performance. Besides. i myself do not like l2sql, ef, l2e because they all process to much work in background, which  results in difficuilt debugging and non-obvious restrictions and workarounds. This is my personal opinion, that's why it's a comment not an answer.

Comment: Ok well I don't think what ORM I'm using is the key to this issue - you could always replace anywhere I've said 'Linq to Entities' in my question with 'dapper-dot-net' and the question of where to handle the transactions still stands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't you start a transaction with high isolation level so that the lock is active at the server side?

Answer (score 2):

You may use **locks** *(pessimistic concurrency model)* or **timestamps** *(optimistic concurrency model)* to deal with concurrency issues.

It is a very wide topic so i would suggest you start by googling for database concurrency.